# Use of one in a passive sentence

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I do not understand the next sentence:

The term "studio apartment" is ***one used frequently*** by British estate agents to describe a small unit of accomodation.

First: Can someone explain to me why the adverb of frequency is placed after the verb "to use"?

The term "studio apartment" is **one frequently used** by British estate agents to describe a small unit of accomodation. *

Second, Can someone explain to me the meaning of "one" in this sentence?

Studio apartment is one of the terms frequently used by.... (It is the sentence that has sense to me)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no special reason for the placement of the adverb; it's just a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 3):

The word *one* in

> The term “studio apartment” is **one** used frequently…

means “a term.” Compare

> Many US presidents were tall. Abraham Lincoln was **one** who was particularly known for his stature. **Another** was George Washington.

Here, both *one* and *another* have the implicit (and elided) complement, *US president*.

I’d also point out that this usage is independent of the passive voice, as is demonstrated by the sentence about President Washington. And consider as a further example

> In many species of songbirds the sexes differ markedly in size or appearance. **One** that demonstrates such *sexual dimorphism* is the Northern Cardinal (*Cardinalis cardinalis*), the male of which is a bright red, while the female is a drab grayish brown.

Here, the verb *demonstrates* is, obviously, in the active voice.